# Why is .pipe not firing off in this Nodejs google.drive.get function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-drive-api

Here is my code:

```
      const dest = await fs.createWriteStream('./src/Pages/downloads/' + fileName + '.' + type);

        await drive.files.get(
        {fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'}, 
        {responseType: 'stream'}, 
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) return console.log(err); 
          res.data.pipe(dest, function(err) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            console.log("pipe worked")
          });
        });
```

A few things that I want to note:

1. This is within an async post request function (explaining the awaits) that take several variables from a google drive file, such as its name, id, and mimetype. These are the "fileName" and "type" variables that show up within the code. They are already predefined and not the problem. So for the sake of this question, assume that the variables are something like var fileId = dsf9ds0f9asdaf09dsfj0, var fileName = test and var type = pdf.
2. The drive.files.get function is an asynchronous call to the Google Drive api that finds the file/folder/item with the specific id noted in "fileId" and then downloads it. What I am trying to achieve here is exporting the file that fits that specific id into the WriteStream as defined by dest.
3. The './src/Pages/downloads/' + fileName + "." + type; path does exist. When I run the fs.access test, it returns "Directory exists".

With all of this said, the res.data.pipe is not firing anything off in the console. Not even the error message. Everything else is working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you got this example from? Is `res.data` an rxjs observable or something?

Comment: This is a snippet from my own code. res.data is the response of the google.drive.get (i.e. the file that it finds). @Alisson